# Як перекласти українською "update" і "upgrade"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Зокрема, цікавить переклад в галузі інформатики. Обидва найчастіше перекладають як *оновити*, *оновлення*.

Який тоді переклад краще використовувати для *upgrade*, щоб відрізнити його від *update*?

Comment: Без контексту тут нічого не вдієш. Бо в різних сферах застосування слова *update* і *update* вживаються в різних значеннях. Навіть у системах одного типу вони можуть вживатися в фактично протилежних значеннях.

Comment: Наприклад, в менеджері пакетів `deb`: команда `update` перевіряє, які пакети доступні для оновлення (тобто оновлює перелік доступних із сервера пакетів), а команда `upgrade` власне оновлює всі пакети, доступні для оновлення. В менеджері же пакетів `yum`: першу операцію виконує команда `check-update`, а другу — команда `update`. Тобто `deb upgrade` = `yum update`.

Comment: Тицьніть пальцем на приклади речень зі словами `update` і `upgrade`, які би пояснювали значення, в яких Ви хочете їх перекласти.

Answer (score 16):

Слова *update* та *upgrade* мають різні значення. За "Cambridge Dictionary":

> - **upgrade** - покращити якість або ефективність чого-небудь, наприклад, машини або комп'ютерної програми; дати людині важливішу роботу або посаду [[1]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upgrade);
> - **update** - осучаснити щось, зробити його більш відповідним для використання в даний час шляхом додавання нової інформації або зміни його конструкції [[2]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/update).

Та й з будови даних слів можна зробити висновки щодо їхнього значення: *up-grade* (на рівень вище), *up to date* або *up-to-date* (сучасний, свіжий).

Тобто *upgrade* можемо перекласти як "покращення", "вдосконалення", а *update* - це "оновлення", "осучаснення".

Answer (score 10):

Здається, в англійській мові слово *update* частіше застосовується до програмного забезпечення (ПЗ), а *upgrade* - до апаратного. Тому, якщо мова йде про IT-галузь, то пропоную перекласти ось так:

- *update* - *оновити*
- *upgrade* - *модернізувати* (приклад використання у контексті програмного забезпечення [тут](http://www.kmu.gov.ua/document/247997520/Food_safety_Market_Serveillance.pdf), [тут](http://it-tehnolog.com/statti/prosluhovuvannya-mobilnogo-telefonu), у контексті апаратного - [тут](http://uchni.com.ua/informatika/1375/index.html))