# Чи є різниця між оновленням і апдейтом?

Tags: іншомовні-слова

У змі звично використовують слово **апдейт** там, де йдеться суто про комп'ютерні програми. Що заважає використовувати тільки **оновлення** (окрім любові до іншомовних слів)? Чи є мовленнєві ситуації не про комп'ютерні програми, коли **апдейт** краще передає зміст висловлювання, ніж український відповідник **оновлення**? Чи є у слова **апдейт** такі значення, яких не має оновлення?

Цитати для контексту питання:

> Апдейт (від англ. Update – оновлення) – термін англійського
>   походження, який часто використовується в сленгу SEO-оптимізаторів
>   (іноді в середовищі оптимізаторів можна зустріти скорочення «ап») і
>   буквально означає «оновлення даних». Таким чином, апдейтом можна
>   вважати оновлення (зміну) певної сторінки на сайті або її зовнішнього
>   вигляду.

[igroup.com.ua/seo-articles/apdejt/](http://igroup.com.ua/seo-articles/apdejt/)

Апдейт=програмне оновлення:

> Коли буде апдейт PageRank? Оновлення тулбарного показника PageRank в
>   цьому році більше не буде, заявив Метт Каттс у своєму Twitter.

[igroup.com.ua/news/koly-bude-apdejt-pagerank/](http://igroup.com.ua/news/koly-bude-apdejt-pagerank/)

Comment: *[Keep me updated](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/172167/21952)*, тобто тримати в курсі.

Answer (score 1):

На цьому сайті вже було схоже [питання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/760/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E-update-%D1%96-upgrade) і був виконаний переклад дієслів "update" та "upgrade". І як було зазначено, "update" вживається, коли йдеться про програмне забезпечення і був запропонований переклад "оновлення".

Гугл дає також варіант "оновлення" і те ж саме каже [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/apdeit) (а також там є варіант "обнова). Тому можете заміняти слово "апдейт" українським відповідником "оновлення".

Answer (score 0):

Оновлення і апдейт є синонімами. Термін не є специфічним тільки для SEO-оптимізаторів. Операційні системи комп'ютерів/смартфонів також викачують оновлення/апдейти з виправленнями помилок функціоналу програм або з доданим новим функціоналом.